# How to re-render data from a formset when validation fails

Tags: python, django

I have a form a formset in it. When validation fails, I want to re-render the page with the errors as well as all of the data that was entered by the user.

Here is my RequestedPartners object:

```
class RequestedPartners(models.Model):
    first_nm = models.CharField('Requested Partner First Name', max_length=100)
    last_nm = models.CharField('Requested Partner Last Name', max_length=100)
    player = models.ManyToManyField(Players)
```

Here is my RequestedPartners form:

```
class RequestedPartnersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RequestedPartners
        fields = ['first_nm', 'last_nm']

    def clean_first_nm(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['first_nm'].upper()

    def clean_last_nm(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['last_nm'].upper()
```

This is from my post method in views.py:

```
    RequestedPartnersFormSet = modelformset_factory(RequestedPartners, fields=('first_nm', 'last_nm', 'player'))
    myFormset = RequestedPartnersFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if bound_form.is_valid() and lineItemsForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        bound_form.save()
        players = Players()
        players.first_nm = bound_form.cleaned_data['first_nm']
        players.last_nm = bound_form.cleaned_data['last_nm']
        players.email = bound_form.cleaned_data['email']
        players.save()

        forms = myFormset.save(commit=False)
        for form in forms:
            form.player = players
            form.save()

        return redirect(reverse('end_registration'))
    else:
        RequestedPartnersFormSet = formset_factory(RequestedPartnersForm, extra=3)
        reshowFormset = RequestedPartnersFormSet(initial=[????])
```

So, if one of the forms on the page is invalid, I need to be able to re-show everything that the user entered, but I don't know how to get the data from myFormset into the 'reshowFormset' variable.

It seems like I need to loop through the myFormset object, but when I tried to use the forms = myFormset.save(commit=False) line in the else block, Django reminded me that the data couldn't be saved because it is invalid.

So my question is, how do I get the submitted data from myFormset into the reshowFormset object that is going back into the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simply:

```
reshowFormset = RequestedPartnersFormSet(request.POST)
```

You can now render the form `reshowFormset` in your view and it will show the submitted user data. You don't even need a separate variable name for it. Django handles invalid user data automatically for you.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thank you.

I had to add a line so that the Players object didn't show up on the form.

            RequestedPartnersFormSet = formset_factory(RequestedPartnersForm, extra=3)
            reshowFormset = RequestedPartnersFormSet(request.POST)